# Test whether MIN would work over ROW_NUMBER

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Situation:**

I have three columns:

- id
- date
- tx_id

The primary id column is tx_id and is unique in the table. Each tx_id is tied to an id and it has a record date. I would like to test whether or not the tx_id is incremental.

**Objective:**

I need to extract the first tx_id by id but I want to prevent using `ROW_NUMBER` 
i.e

`select id, date, tx_id, row_number() over(partition by id order by date asc) as First_transaction_id from table`

and simply use

`select id, date, MIN(tx_id) as First_transaction_id from table`

So how can i make sure since i have more than 50 millions of ids that by using `MIN`tx_id will yield the earliest transaction for each id?

How can i add a flag column to segment those that don't satisfy the condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can i make sure since i have more than 50 millions of ids that by using MINtx_id will yield the earliest transaction for each id?

Simply do the comparison:

You can get the exceptions with logic like this:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
              min(tx_id) over (partition by id) as min_tx_id,
              rank() over (partition by id order by date) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where tx_id = min_tx_id and seqnum > 1;
```

Note:  this uses `rank()`.  It seems possible that there could be two transactions for an `id` on the same date.

Comment: i fiddled around and it seems it works, but i got system out of memory exception when using it on the actual data. any reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

use corelated sunquery

```
select t.* from table_name t
where t.date= ( select min(date) from table_name
                 t1 where t1.id=t.id)
```

Comment: though, how will i test for sure  that the tx_id is incremental and therefore the lowest tx_id was the first inputted (based on the date)